# Fading in items incrementally using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, settimeout

I realize this has been asked before. I did research, but am still having issues with this. Here's the HTML. I need each block of text to fade in incrementally:

```
<div id="home-landing-text">
    <span class="block">When A Building Is</span> 
    <span class="block">The Last of Its Kind,</span>
    <span class="block">It Deserves To Be Truly</span>
    <span class="block">Memorable.</span>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
var i = 0;
$('#home-landing-text span').each( function () {
    i = i + 1.5;
    var that = $(this);
    setTimeout( function () {
        that.css('opacity', 1);
    }, i );
});
```

And the CSS:

```
#home-landing-text span{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

They all fade in together. Any clues as to why? PS, fadeIn() does not work, because it turns them into inline-blocks, but they need to be blocks. I tried fadeTo(), but ran into the same issue. I think the timer isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second param in the `setTimeout` function is the delay in milliseconds.
So you should increase `i` in 1500.

```
var i = 0;
$('#home-landing-text span').each( function () {
    i = i + 1500;
    var that = $(this);
    setTimeout( function () {
        that.css('opacity', 1);
    }, i );
});
```

Comment: Haha! How silly!! Ok you're right. Thank you. Also, thank you to everyone else, but I will accept this as the answer since it provided the code, and used what I already had.

Answer (score 2):

maybe 1.5ms isn't enough for you to notice? 1000ms = 1 second

Answer (score 1):

You have an iteration counter in jQuery's each, better use that:

```
$('#home-landing-text span').each( function (iterationCount) {
    var that = $(this);
    setTimeout( function () {
        that.css('opacity', 1);
    }, iterationCount * 1500 );
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dd4p07ux/)

Comment: I think I'll go with the solutions below, because I want finer control over the count. I'm actually thinking of starting i at -1500 so that the first one starts immediately. I would prefer to have that kind of flexibility without it getting too complicated.

Comment: @JordanCarter your choice, but starting at -1500 isn't going to work and with this solution the first one starts immediatly, as `iterationCount` is 0 for the first iteration

Comment: It does work if I start i at -1500. Actually, I like your solution now. Both are very good solutions, thank you.